# How to log in to facebook with test user from Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-test-users

I want to test the [game requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/gamerequests) feature and therefore I use [test users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users#managetool).
I want to login to my Android app with a test user that I created.

I been trying to use the `AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken` method as follow:

```
AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(
                    new AccessToken(
                            testAccessToken,
                            context.getString(R.string.facebook_app_id),
                            testUserId,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null)

            );
```

But when I try to initiate the game request dialog it ask me to login with username and password, and when I do, it won't show the dialog anymore, not showing any errors in the log.

How can I log to my app as a test user, if possible I prefer to only provide the **token** and **user_id**

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I was in a good direction, changing it a bit solved my problem.

```
AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(
                    new AccessToken(
                            testAccessToken,
                            context.getString(R.string.facebook_app_id),
                            testUserId,
                            null,
                            null,
                            AccessTokenSource.TEST_USER,
                            new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 5),
                            new Date())

            );
```

Answer (score -3):

test like this

```
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
//do your logic
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
//oncancel
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
          //erroe
            }
        });
```

Comment: You are telling me how to use facebook login, this question is about test users